# Can we clean the [channel] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391371/all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock-exit-status-2-error-in-a-printer-receive) is related to [go channels](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) but I don't know how to specify this in tags.

When I look at the existing 185 questions tagged [channel](/questions/tagged/channel), I see

- questions related to the go channel (probably only among the most recent questions)
- questions related to (somewhat similar) objects in Java, WCF, C#
- questions related to color channels
- questions related to Youtube channels

And of course the tag isn't described.

I feel we should decide what's to go in this tag. And I propose to

- describe the [channel](/questions/tagged/channel) as related to [this general programming notion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_%28programming%29)
- retag questions which aren't related to the new [channel](/questions/tagged/channel) meaning

All Go questions could keep their [channel](/questions/tagged/channel) tag as it would still be valid. The same could probably be said for some of the java questions (and maybe WCF, I don't know).

Does that sound correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had no answer nor downvote or upvote on the question, and as I totally agree with myself, I'll suggest myself to do as I proposed.

Comment: I was about to comment. Who's stopping you? :P

Comment: For a part of the existing 185 questions, "channel" had a different meaning. Who am I to decide that the one I propose is the good one ? But I'll do it.

Comment: Tag is now described. I'll retag some questions.